# XmlAttributeAttribute DataType Property?

Tags: c#, xml, reflection

I haven't found any exact documentation on this and there's not really much to the question; are we required to use `DataType = "string"` instead of `typeof(string)` when working with the `XmlAttributeAttribute`? For example:

```
XmlAttribute("Description", DataType = "string")
XmlAttribute("Description", typeof(string))
```

Both of the lines above compile; however, when using the `typeof(string)` method, I get an error saying primitive types can't be specified (could this be related to the nesting of classes and overridden properties?).

If you remove the `DataType` all together, for some reason reflection fails and the build won't succeed.

Am I doing something wrong, or is this the way it is meant to be? If the requirement is to use the `DataType` method, then how do you specify custom types such as `enum`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DataType` is used for simple types in the `xsd` namespace, so `string` for example. For complex types you specify the `Type` property of the `XmlAttributeAttribute`. So since `xsd:string` is a simple type in the `xsd` namespace, you use

```
[XmlAttribute("Name", DataType = "string")]
```

If you had, as you've mentioned, a custom enum, you'd do

```
[XmlAttribute("Name", typeof(MyEnum))]
```

Comment: This was the issue; however, there are two things. 1. I had to remove the type specification altogether for enums (not sure why). 2. I am stull unsure as to why this caused a compile time error instead of runtime.